# How can Max() work within sumif in an expression on Qliksense?

Tags: max, sumifs, qliksense

I wrote an expression to find the sum of [Spend by Vendor] for those ranked top 10 in [Benefit].

```
Sum(if([H4 Benefit by Vendor] > Max([H4 Benefit by Vendor],11), [Spend by     Vendor],0))/sum([Spend by Vendor])
```

However, this expression did not work.

I tried to separate the expression into two and tested. (Replaced the Max() part with 0)

1. Sum(if([H4 Benefit by Vendor] >0, [Spend by     Vendor],0))/sum([Spend by Vendor])
2. Max([H4 Benefit by Vendor],11)

They worked fine independently. However, it could not work when combining together.

May I know is there any method to combine these two together?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is comparing the aggregated value with the row value - you can't do this directly but there are a few options as per this [thread](https://community.qlikview.com/thread/185261).

The way I would do this is to set a variable on the load script

```
Temp:
load
    max([H4 Benefit by Vendor]) as maxB
resident TABLENAME;

LET vBenefitMax = peek('maxB');

drop table Temp;
```

and then refer to that in your `If` statement.

```
    Sum(if([H4 Benefit by Vendor] > vBenefitMax, [Spend by Vendor],0))
/ sum([Spend by Vendor])
```